# GNU GCC compiler - aligned attribute

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, memory-alignment

I correctly got the alignment warning

> cast increases required alignment of target type [-Wcast-align]

from the GCC compiler due to the following code:

```
uint8_t array[100];

uint32_t foo;
foo = * ( (uint32_t *) &array[10]);
```

Then I used the `aligned` attribute to figure out the issue:

```
uint8_t array[100] __attribute__ ((aligned(4)));

uint32_t foo;
foo = * ( (uint32_t *) &array[10]);
```

Despite this trick I however got the same warning. Is that normal or the warning should disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it: `&array[10]` won't be 4 byte aligned even with `__attribute__ ((aligned(4)))`, since you are looking at an offset of 10 bytes into a 4 byte aligned array. So you will only be getting 2 byte alignment in this example, and gcc is correct to emit a warning. Try it with an index of say 12, instead of 10, and the warning *might* go away.

Comment: You are right about the array's index error, I wrote the example in one go. However, I tried to use an index multiple of 4 but the warning still remains. Maybe I should disable such type of warnings once aware of having managed them.

Comment: Yes, it depends somewhat on the compiler and compiler version - I tried various versions of gcc and clang and got various different results. Of course you should probably be using a union instead of type punning.

Comment: could you please point me out a worthy example of how using union for my purpose?

Comment: Do you mean something [like that](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXVZZ_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlcpp1313.lelinux.doc/language_ref/cplr188.html)?

Comment: You can either define a union type element, where you have 4 x uint8_t and 1 x uint32_t in the union, or if you only want to use one fixed size of array then it might be more convenient to have a single union containing an array of uint8_t and an array of uint32_t.

Answer (score 2):

`__attribute__ ((aligned(4)))` aligns only the *beginning* of the array, not every single element of it.

If the beginning is aligned and the offset is `10` which is nor dividable by 4 the resulting address will not be aligned.